# Is there an Equivalent of .Net framework's Random.Next(Int32, Int32) in the Java API?

Tags: random, java

I am working on porting an existing VB.Net application to Java, and could not find an equivalent to Random.Next(Int32, Int32).

I could find only `java.util.Random.next(int val)` in the Java API.

Is there an Equivalent of .Net framework's Random.Next(Int32, Int32) in the Java API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Marc says, just adapt `Random.nextInt(int)`, with a couple of sanity checks:

```
public static int nextInt(Random rng, int lower, int upper) {
    if (upper < lower) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    if ((long) upper - lower > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    return rng.nextInt(upper-lower) + lower;
}
```

Comment: why is this necessary ? 
 if ((long) upper - lower > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

Comment: @MahdeTo: Consider nextInt(rng, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE)

Comment: (In particular, think about what would happen in the call to rng.nextInt...)

Answer (score 2):

no but you can have it this way:

```
public static int randomInRange(int min, int max){
      return min+Random.next(max-min);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider RandomUtils from Apache Commons Lang:

http://commons.apache.org/lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang/math/RandomUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use [Random.nextInt(int)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) specifying the range, and then just add the minimum value? i.e. rand.nextInt(12) + 5

Comment: rand.nextInt(max) + min is wrong; this returns integers greater than max?

Comment: Which is why I used the word **range**, not max

Answer (score 0):

Call to `Random.Next(x, y)` can be translated to something like `Random.nextInt(y - x) + x;`